# Microsoft Azure - Infrastructure Logs Exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I've got a few Cloud Service deployments and every now and then I see this exception being raised under **Microsoft Azure infrastructure logs**

```
0   Message="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length

Server stack trace: 
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.RdpRemoteEndpointFinder.GetRemoteEndpoint(Socket clientSocket, Stream peekBuffer)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.IRemoteEndpointFinder.GetRemoteEndpoint(Socket clientSocket, Stream peekBuffer)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.RemoteForwardingService.ClientConnected(Object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.TcpSocketServer.OnClientConnected(ConnectionEventArgs e)"      0   0       00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    15d2502e-8793-435d-b9fa-87e67a7bba29    MySolution.Azure.MyWorkerRole_IN_0  5f0332c190e24146a849d7937ecccc13    23/05/2016 05:40:43
```

Any idea of why this is being raised and how I can avoid it?

Comment: Interesting.. I'll forward this on to the azure team

Comment: Can you post more info about your configs?